# Как в Unity управлять с помощью кода?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу сделать игру по типу [RubyWarrior](https://www.bloc.io/ruby-warrior#/). Как в Unity возможно такое сделать? Примеров найти не могу. Либо я не правильно веду свой поиск? Если кто сталкивался с подобным прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Создаёте игровой уровень.
- Добавляете поверх него InputField и настраиваете, как вам требуется.
- Пишите парсер кода. (Читает построчно текст и добавляет команды. Например, "если строчка Warrior.Forward!" - добавить в очередь команду "сдвинуть вперёд" и т.д.)
- Добавляете кнопку, по нажатию которой получается текст из InputField, прогоняется через парсер и возвращает команды для воина.
- Применяете команды к воину.

Comment: Это конечно как вариант. Но это как то не то. Что если человек решит задачу по другому, и решение будет правильным. А я этого не предусмотрю в условии. И моя игра скажет этому человеку, что его решение не верно.